# Connect to Samba shares from Mac OS that has the same address but different port

Tags: macos, samba, network-drive

I have MacOS Ventura 13.5.1 (22G90) and two remote Samba shares. They have the same url, same username and passwords but a different ports. The behaviour on Mac and smbutil command is quite strange.

When I restart the Mac and connect to one share (let say on port 10002) it connects successfully and I can use my share. When I'm trying to connect to other share (on port 10003) it connects to the same share as before. It looks like it sees that I'm connected to the url (without port number) and just shows me the same data. The smbutil command lines does the same:

```
pfaro@C02FP1Z8MD6P ~ % smbutil view -g //url:10003
Share                                           Type    Comments
-------------------------------
Fizyka                                          Disk    FIzyka's Fizyka in HGST HTS 541010A9E680
IPC$                                            Pipe    IPC Service (RT-AX86U)
Backup                                          Disk    Backup's Backup in HGST HTS 541010A9E680

3 shares listed
pfaro@C02FP1Z8MD6P ~ % smbutil view -g //url:10002 
Share                                           Type    Comments
-------------------------------
Fizyka                                          Disk    FIzyka's Fizyka in HGST HTS 541010A9E680
IPC$                                            Pipe    IPC Service (RT-AX86U)
Backup                                          Disk    Backup's Backup in HGST HTS 541010A9E680
```

When I restart the Mac and start from the other share (port 10003) it correctly shows me its data but I cannot connect to the first one (on port 10002). This is kind of joke as every app I'm using on my phone or TV don't have problem with that but Mac has.

Is there any workaround for that?